# I want the index value when reading one data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

To create a custom loss function, I want the index value when reading one data.

The value of index when one data is read is the output result below, it is the value of 29 of 1/90000 1,29 / 90000.
Where can this value be obtained?

```py
1/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 12:04:23 - loss: 138.6650 
  29/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 27:36 - loss: 138.3218 
  59/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 14:52 - loss: 138.4405 
  90/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 10:35 - loss: 138.4409 
  121/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 8:29 - loss: 138.3823 
  152/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 7:16 - loss: 138.3635 
  182/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 6:28 - loss: 138.3305 
  213/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 5:53 - loss: 138.2896 
  245/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 5:25 - loss: 138.2487
```

Comment: Why do you need it? It is indicating the number of examples trained.

Comment: I want to use that value to create a custom loss function.
I want to know the number of times the loss function has been called.

Comment: The number of times the loss function is called depends on the mini-batch size and not the number indicated.

Comment: Batch size is set to 1.
So I think it will be counted by the number of data read.
Even in that case, can it be called only once?

Comment: Loss function is called once per batch.